What can I use?
So I want something probably a token which should have a Unique token no. And serial no. For all claimed token in sol network wallet
And we can check in wallets after connecting to it if it has that token by its serial no. Or token I'd in that connected wallet !
What can I use something like that ?
Or is it possible to built something on solana in very sort span of time 1-2 days for newbie

Maybe to use the Metaplex toolkit: https://developers.metaplex.com/

thanks you for the suggestion
